# What's the best way to set up a multipage web application using webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Sorry if the question is poorly formatted/unclear, I'm new to stack overflow!

I'm a beginner in webdev and I'm making a website with multiple pages, and each page needs to load a different js file. I'd like to use webpack as the js file for each page would contain several imports and I don't want a lot of script tags in each html page. To my knowledge webpack is better for single page applications, but if I want to have one output bundle for each page, what would be the best way to achieve that? I plan to place each bundle js file in a script tag for each page of the website.

Another thing: would it be ok to place the bundles in the public folder such that I can place them in the script tags (otherwise I'm not sure how to access them), or is there some reason why I shouldn't do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! As a new user, I'd recommend you review [ask].  For this question: can you narrow it to only ask one specific question, including a [mcve] and/or example where relevant?  For this question, perhaps some dummy code and an example of your desired output hierarchy? Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In webpack.config.js.
Add multiple output fields to entry.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
     app: './src/app.js',
     adminApp: './src/adminApp.js'
   }
};
```